# is there a way to call onClick method inside a function , what should i pass to the method in the parameters?

Tags: java, android

i'm working on A project same like the calculator app but with 4 fields , an app to calculate the score for 4 players , also contains a custom numpad (numbers,operator,clear and equal button) , i can't figure out how to apply the buttons methods on the 4 fields(editText)....
i have searched a lot but i could't find anything related

i've tried (onFocusChangeListener , onTouchListener) with edit texts , but the main problem was when i call the buttons methods inside the onFocusChangeListener (which i used to determine which edit text is selected) the button methods require a parameter , and i don't know what should i pass to the method parameter....

...
like so
...

```
playerTwoScore.setOnFocusChangeListener(new 
View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus){
                   onClick("here is my problem");
            }
        }
    });
```

i expect that when i tab on the first edit text i will be able to click on the buttons and do like "1 + 1 = 2"
and when i tab on the second edit text i will able to do the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should us `TextWatcher`

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

Comment: You call your add function inside of aftertextchange

Comment: thanks , it really worked but i faced another issue , i have a function updateScreen(); ...... i use it to set text in editText .....  ..... i want it also to check which editText is selected and apply the function

Comment: While in your text watcher , use an integer to specify which edittext are u ine for ex : int = 1 where edittext1..... dont forget to upvote my answer

Comment: thank you , i'm new to stackOverFlow , i don't know how to upvote , tell me how would i do it....

Comment: the up arrow above the number left of the answer , you are welcome